# How do I format a cell, only when it's not empty, based on the input of another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm working on a spreadsheet in Google Sheets for multiple people, and indicate in a column who the person the information on that row pertains to. I want to format cells on that column, only when they're not empty, based on what person is selected in another cell.

I can create functions to format things based on another cell's entry, but I don't know how to compound that with a function for not being empty. Sorry if this is super basic, I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. This is a super simple thing to do.
1) Highlight the column where the person's name appears.
2) From the main menu, select Format, Conditional formatting.
3) In the sidebar click add a new rule. what you want to do is create one rule for each name that appears (or could appear) in that column.
4) Under "Format cells if, select "Text is exactly"
5) Type the name in the cell where it says Value or Formula
6) Choose a background colour to suit.
7) Click Done.
8) Repeat steps 3 to 7 for each person; but change the background colour in each case.

Here's an example.

---

[image]